# How to calculate max string-length of a node-set?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, libxslt

I am trying to use XSLT to turn an XML document into plain text tables for human consumption. I am using `xsltproc`, which only implements XSLT 1.0 (so `max` is from EXSLT actually).

I tried the below, but the commented-out definition fails because `string-length` returns only a single value (the length of the *first* node's string value), not a node-set like `max` wants.

Transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- vim: set sts=2 sw=2: -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- <xsl:variable name="max_a_width" select="math:max(string-length(data/@a))"/> -->
    <xsl:variable name="max_a_width" select="string-length(data/@a)"/>
    <xsl:text>+-</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="str:padding($max_a_width, '-')"/><xsl:text>-+&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="data">
      <xsl:text>| </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="@a"/><xsl:value-of select="str:padding($max_a_width - string-length(@a), ' ')"/><xsl:text> |&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text>+-</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="str:padding($max_a_width, '-')"/><xsl:text>-+&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- vim: set sts=2 sw=2: -->
<root>
  <data a="aa"/>
  <data a="aaa"/>
  <data a="a"/>
</root>
```

Output:

```
+----+
| aa |
| aaa |
| a  |
+----+
```

In order to make the right border line up, I need to have the actual maximum value in the variable. (In my real example I will have column headers and multiple columns, but they are not necessary to reproduce the problem).

If it makes it easier to find a solution, I *can* guarantee that the data values will never contain spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:variable name="max_a_width">
  <xsl:for-each select="data">
    <xsl:sort select="string-length(@a)" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
      <xsl:value-of select="string-length(@a)" />
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

This is the general method of picking from an ordered list of derived values in XSLT 1.0.

If you want to pick the minimum/maximum from actual (natively sortable) values, you can take a short-cut:

```
<xsl:variable name="max_a" select="//a[not(. &lt; //a)][1]" />
```

Answer (score 2):

This is how to do this using **EXSLT** `math:max()`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
xmlns:math="http://exslt.org/math" 
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:variable name="lengths">
        <xsl:for-each select="data">
            <length><xsl:value-of select="string-length(@a)"/></length>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="max_a_width" select="math:max(exsl:node-set($lengths)/length)"/>
    <!-- the rest -->
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple recursive template. Run it with the same XSLT file as input to test it. This is of course easier with XSLT 2 or XQuery...

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template name="maxlen">
    <xsl:param name="input" />
    <xsl:param name="max-so-far" select="0" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not($input)">
        <xsl:value-of select="$max-so-far" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($input[1]) &gt; $max-so-far">
        <xsl:call-template name="maxlen">
          <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input[position() &gt; 1]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="max-so-far"
            select="string-length($input[1])" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="maxlen">
          <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$input[position() &gt; 1]" />
          <xsl:with-param name="max-so-far" select="$max-so-far" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:variable name="input">
    <test>
      <string>123456789012345678901234</string>
      <string>12345678901234</string>
      <string>1234567890</string>
      <string>12345678901234567890123456</string>
    </test>
  </xsl:variable>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
      <xsl:call-template name="maxlen">
        <xsl:with-param name="input" select="//test/string" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```